# Сериализация простыми словами

Tags: java, android, serialize

Много раз встречал эту "сериализацию" на разных ресурсах, часто связано с JSON.

Объясните, пожалуйста, простыми словами, что такое сериализация, где и зачем ее применяют ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Сериализация — это преобразование объекта или дерева объектов в какой-либо формат (обычно текстовый или в набор байт) с тем, чтобы потом исходные объекты можно было восстановить из этого формата. Используется, например, для сохранения состояния программы (то есть, некоторых её объектов) между запусками. Или для передачи данных между различными экземплярами программы (или различными программами), например, по сети.

Главная идея состоит в том, что сериализованный формат — набор байт или строка, которую можно легко сохранить на диск или передать другому процессу (возможно, находящемуся на другом хосте), в отличие от самого объекта. А значит, задача сохранения/передачи объекта (или группы объектов) при этом сводится к простой задаче сохранения/передачи набора байт или строки.

JSON — один из популярных форматов для сериализации, он текстовый, легковесный и легко читается человеком.

Пример: если у вас есть класс

```
class Test
{
    int length;
    String name;

    public Test(int length, String name)
    {
        this.length = length;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Объект этого класса в сериализованной форме может иметь вид

```
{ "length": 25, "name": "Имя" }
```

Саму сериализацию (и десериализацию) можно производить вручную, или пользоваться соответствующими библиотеками/фреймворками.

Существуют и бинарные форматы сериализации, например, [protobuf](https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/javatutorial/).

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, сериализация это представление сущности в строке. Сохранение это отдельный процесс.

Comment: @Steve: Не обязательно, вполне возможна и бинарная сериализация.

Comment: Куда сохраняется сущность при сериализации?

Comment: @Steve: Куда угодно. В файл, в память, в поток, ...

Comment: Вряд ли есть выражение, которое сохраняет сериализацию, как полный цикл сериализации, который входит в настоящее понятие сериализации. Хранение в памяти сериализованной сущности во время выполнения самой сериализации вряд ли является сохранением в память. Хотя, может я не прав.

Comment: @Steve: Ничего не понял :-\

Comment: Сериализация - преобразование, но не сохранение.

Comment: @Steve: Ну да, но я вроде и не утверждал обратное. Сериализация преобразует объект в набор байт/строку, а куда именно они попадают, вопрос второстепенный.

Comment: @Steve: Улучшил ответ.

Comment: Все время я имел ввиду, что сериализация ничего не сохраняет, а только преобразует в формат для хранения. Записать (сохранить) полученный результат преобразования можно уже после сериализации по желанию. То есть сериализация - это преобразование  объекта для удобного хранения, но не сохранение. К примеру, конструкция JSON.stringify() только преобразует но никуда ничего не записывает!

Comment: @Steve: Но я не имел в виду под словом «сохранять» запись в файл или ещё куда-то. Сохранение в память настолько же имеет смысл, как и в файл. Смысл сериализации в том, что это обратимое преобразование. Я даже специально отредактировал ответ с акцентом на то, что это преобразование.

Comment: JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,5]); Где в этом выражении сохранение?

Comment: @Steve: Объект сохраняется в строку, разумеется.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify 
Там отдельно описано преобразование и преобразование с сохранением, если оно требуется. Если бы я не знал что такое сериализация, то прочитав ответ решил бы, что это процесс преобразования и сохранения в одном действии. Само по себе сериализация ничего не сохраняет. Определение переменной со значением сериализованной сущности не является сохранением в контексте сериализации.

Comment: @Steve: Документация не вполне корректна вот в каком смысле. Сохранение объекта в строку — это вполне себе сохранение. А вот сохранение этой самой _строки_ (в local storage, или в файл, или по сети, или ещё как-нибудь) — это отдельная тема. В примере из документации создавалась строка и укладывалась в local storage.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ с примером!

Comment: @researcher: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5):

Сериализация в общем виде - это процесс сохранения объекта в виде последовательности байт, чтобы в будущем по этой последовательности можно было бы восстановить исходный объект. В частном случае - это может быть сохранение в текстовую строку, хотя это далеко не обязательно.

Если объект сериализуется в текстовую строку, то тут могут быть разные форматы, включая XML и упомянутый в вопросе JSON. Последний для этой цели наиболее популярен в последнее время, т.к. JSON - это и так представление объекта в том формате, как объект создается в JavaScript. Собственно, JSON и переводится как JavaScript Object Notation.

Сериализацию можно использовать для хранения объектов на диске, для передачи его по сети или для передачи объекта другому процессу.

Процесс, обратный сериализации, называется десереализация. В случае, если другой процесс получает строку JSON, то он должен десереализовать строку в объект.

Comment: спасибо за пояснение!

Answer (score 3):

Если на кошках
Вы пишете эмулятор кота - тамагочи. У вас есть объект класс cat

```
class Cat {
   private int age;
   private int weight;
   // other cat logic
}
```

Вы хотите, чтобы при следующем запуске приложения этот же кот продолжал жить своей жизнью, а не пересоздался заново. Для этого вы реализуете сериализацию\десериализацию кота - то есть созранение\загрузку. Как - так как вам удобно. Можно сделать его Serializable и хранить в бинарном виде, можно сохранять в текстовый файл как JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), можно в базе хранить. Главное - вы сохраняете каким-то образом его состояние (в данном случае - поля), и потом, когда вам это будет нужно, их загружаете.
Так же сериализованного кота можно будет например передать по сети на сервер. То есть вы передаете его состояние, а сервер у себя создаст новый объект класса Cat и установит  у него это состояние (age и weight).

Comment: спасибо за простой пример!

Answer (score 2):

Сериализация используется для хранения сущностей в виде строки. Например можно взять объект, сериализовать и записать в базу данных.

Json - формат представления данных. Он может представлять объекты или массивы. Эти сущности также можно сериализовать. Если вывести сериализованый объект в Json, то можно получить строку сериализованного объекта.

Answer (score 1):

Сериализация - это преобразование данных.
Если из более "понятного" в менее - это сериализация.
А наоборот - десериализация.

Десериализовывать данные нужно, например, чтобы придать им человеко-читаемы вид, или такой формат, который можно и\или удобно использовать в работе приложение.

Сериализовать данные нужно, например, для хранения или пересылки. Потому что - есть определённый формат хранения\пересылки данных и данные нужно в него преобразовать.

Очень часто речь идёт о преобразовании в JSON - для отправки на сервер - это сериализация. И обратно - для использования в приложении - это десериализация.

Например - в интерфейсе приложения данные должны быть представлены в виде таблицы - и их нужно правильно достать из JSON и напихать в ячейки. Потом эти данные изменит пользователь и их нужно будет преобразовать обратно в дерево JSON, чтобы отправить на сервер.

Вот и всё...
А вот это вот "процесс перевода структуры данных в последовательность байтов" - видимо сухая формулировка из старого учебника, которая мало способствует пониманию.

Comment: Понятность тут на втором плане. Главное - обеспечить полное сохранение и воссоздание в том же виде, причём сохранение может быть и в бинарном формате.